# In typescript, why do the | and & operators flip their meaning when used on function types?

Tags: typescript, types, declare

[In this code, `example1` and `example2` are confusing me](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBAYgjFAvFAFAQwFxQM7AE4CWAdgOYA0UARhroaQJRIB8UAbgPYEAmA3AFChIsAExJUmKEQCuAW0oQ8FatLkLGiFh278+AY3ZFcUCAA80MsABsIcLPCgAyEWPRZaxElAA+k2fMVUbvge3r6qeOosAN4Avnym5lY2KABEABIQlpbsKRQpAOrseJZcKfTxZhbWcChwFMLlAPSNxpVJNemZ2blQDVDNUACieHhFAIRh-lAE2JLswFBo2NgEJERolNZQwOxQYGh45hDAClDsAGbb4NDupAB0D+JEXGwEutCsCtho5XoGRgkqhBhHYED4YKJkK4cMFSKEVP4lEE6J4fAi1MwoLE+ANAUlhKkMlkcnlCsVSowBsNRngJgBBPAkWQQIgLC5XIS3TwzOYLJYrNYbLY7PYHI4nPBnS6CaBECCfPA4lp46wEuq9SktanjKAMpkyFls6XXSanHlEeaLZardabaAi-aHA0SqUc2XyhRK1qJVWErokjX9LUjHV65ms10ymEo6azC1862Cu3bXaO8WndlRuUKvhe-SGBYqiAAZiw6MlPi5YnwUmgVJDtKgABUTQAhdjsaxoIix3lWgW24W7LN+U6V2EkP4F71AgAsZdHFejIWQcCnALa1gArAvwqEq8gUucOylcwN8xufRAAGxYKISLkxRxY6imvBP5D3rBHk9P+s0iYWyEAByKJFmRDweCgGJgN7eN+xtIV7WHE1QPA5dSCgp8nDA19yyw4C7igL0AAVRkgPBQCgYDKFgnkZBmFY4WIN1qLAh8JwIqgpAWPAIAARykAg+JeFiozQvDFwIu510LTcIAAdjvDiUWwl9d38D8sQkH8A1fLcYiAA):

```
type F1 = (a: string, b:string) => void;
type F2 = (a: number, b:number) => void;

//   re: example 1 and 2: 
//   After the =, | means "or" and & means "and"
//   Before the =, & means "or" and | means "and"
const example1: F1 & F2 = (a: string | number, b: string | number) => {}
example1("Hello", "World")
example1(1, 2)
// example1("Hello", 2) // Error! number is not assignable to parameter of type string... (and vice versa)

const example2: F1 | F2 = (a: string | number, b: string | number) => {}
// example2("Hello", "World") // Error! Argument of type string is not assignable to parameter of type never
// example2(1, 2) // Error! Argument of type number is not assignable to parameter of type never
// example2("Hello", 2) // Error! Argument of type string is not assignable to parameter of type never

//   re: example 3,4,5:
//   Before the =, | means "or"
// const example3: number | string = true // Error! Type Boolean is not assignable to type number | string
const example4: number | string = 1
const example5: number | string = "foo"

//   re: example 6,7
//   Before the =, & means "and"
// const example6: {a: string} & {b: number} = {a: "foo"} // Error! Type '{ a: string; }' is not assignable to type '{ a: string; } & { b: number; }'. 
// Property 'b' is missing in type '{ a: string; }' but required in type '{ b: number; }'.
const example7: {a: string} & {b: number} = {a: "foo", b: 5}
```

To me it seems like the operators in `example1` and `example2` (before the `=`) are behaving the opposite way from the others. Here's how I would *expect* these examples to work:

```
const example1: F1 & F2 = (a: string | number, b: string | number) => {}
// example2("Hello", "World") // Error! Argument of type string is not assignable to parameter of type never
// example2(1, 2) // Error! Argument of type number is not assignable to parameter of type never
// example2("Hello", 2) // Error! Argument of type string is not assignable to parameter of type never

const example2: F1 | F2 = (a: string | number, b: string | number) => {}
example1("Hello", "World")
example1(1, 2)
// example1("Hello", 2) // Error! number is not assignable to parameter of type string... (and vice versa)
```

It would also make sense to me if `example1` didn't even compile, since "type of string !== type of number".

Why isn't this working as *expected*?

Comment: Feel free to edit this title. I'm sure it can be better

Answer (score 2):

With these types,

```
type F1 = (a: string, b:string) => void;
type F2 = (a: number, b:number) => void;
```

and this declaration of `example1`,

```
const example1: F1 & F2 = (a: string | number, b: string | number) => {}
```

`example1` has declared type `F1 & F2`, so it can be called both as a function of two strings and as a function of two numbers. But it *can't* be called with a mix of the two arguments. The function value you *assigned* to it could, but `F1 & F2` is strictly a supertype of `(a: string | number, b: string | number) => void`, so we lost information when we assigned to a variable with a static supertype, in the same way that assigning the number `3` to a variable of type `unknown` loses information.

```
const example2: F1 | F2 = (a: string | number, b: string | number) => {}
```

The type of `example2` is the type of either functions which can be called with `string` arguments *or* those that can be called with `number` arguments. The function you're assigning to it can be called with either, so the assignment is fine.

But we can never call this function. At all. We would have to pass it two arguments, where those arguments are compatible with both the `F1` and `F2` signatures. `F1` expects `string` and `F2` expects `number`, so we need to pass something that's both a string *and* a number, i.e. `string & number`. And `string & number` is `never`, the empty type.

The reason the `|` turns into an `&` in that second function is due to a little thing called [variance](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Variance_(computer_science)). Function arguments are contravariant, so `((a: A1) => B1) & ((a: A2) => B2)` is equal to `(a: A1 | A2) => B1 & B2` and `((a: A1) => B1) | ((a: A2) => B2)` is equal to `(a: A1 & A2) => B1 | B2`. You can read that Wikipedia page for more details on the math behind it, or write out what the "and" and "or" type means and follow your intuition.

Comment: "`example1` has declared type `F1 & F2`, so it can be called both as a function of two strings and as a function of two numbers." Okay, but why can't you say, "`example6` has declared type `{a: string} & {b: number}`, so it can be <del>called</del>assigned both as an object of `{a: string}` and as an object of `{b: number}`?" (`const example6: {a: string} & {b: number} = {a: "foo"}` errors.)

Comment: When you're assigning to a variable of intersection type, the thing you're assigning to it must be compatible with both of the types. When you're *using* the variable, you can freely treat it as either at your discretion. For unions, it's the opposite. You can assign either to it at your discretion but when you use it you have to account for both possibilities. It's an inversion of control. In your `example1`, you're talking about using the variable (i.e. the variable making a promise to you), whereas in `example6` you're talking about assignment (i.e. you making a promise to the variable).

Comment: I feel like the answer to my question is in here, but I'm struggling to understand the way you've worded it. No offense intended, and I apologize because this isn't very actionable feedback. Maybe it would help if your explanation and the associated example code were closer together?

Answer (score 2):

It is true that the situation may be confusing regarding the *arguments* of types of function, when these functions are combined together.

@Bishwajitjha is not totally wrong in trying to explain it with the Set theory, even though simple diagrams may be enough.

## Intersection `F1 & F2` of function types

[image: Intersection of F1 and F2 sets]

```
const example1: F1 & F2
```

`example1` function can be called both as F1 and as F2. Therefore it corresponds to a [**TypeScript function overload**](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/functions.html#function-overloads):

- you can execute it as if it were an F1 (`example1("Hello", "World")`),
- or as if it were an F2 (`example1(1, 2)`),
- but you cannot mix (error for `example1("Hello", 2)`)

It is even easier to see how TypeScript handles the `F1 & F2` intersection as an overload, if they had return types:

```
// Overload demonstration
type F1b = (a: string, b:string) => string;
type F2b = (a: number, b:number) => number;

declare const example1b: F1b & F2b;

const r1b1 = example1b("foo", "bar") // string
parseInt(r1b1) // Okay
r1b1.toFixed() // Error! Property 'toFixed' does not exist on type 'string'

const r1b2 = example1b(1, 2) // number
parseInt(r1b2) // Error! Argument of type 'number' is not assignable to parameter of type 'string'.
r1b2.toFixed() // Okay

declare const r1b3: ReturnType<F1b & F2b> // When TS must choose, it uses the last overload => number
parseInt(r1b3) // Error! Argument of type 'number' is not assignable to parameter of type 'string'.
r1b3.toFixed() // Okay

declare const r1b4: ReturnType<F2b & F1b> // When TS must choose, it uses the last overload => string
parseInt(r1b4) // Okay
r1b4.toFixed() // Error! Property 'toFixed' does not exist on type 'string'
```

## Union `F1 | F2` of function types

[image: Union of F1 and F2 sets]

```
const example2: F1 | F2
```

Here it is more complex, because it does not match a specific TypeScript construct.

`example2` may be just an F1, or just an F2, or an overload of both. Because the union does not provide any further information, when we try using `example2`, we must account for all these possibilities *simultaneously*: https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/everyday-types.html#working-with-union-types

- as an F1, it would need both its arguments as `string`
- as an F2, it would need both its arguments as `number`
- as an F1 & F2, it can have either both as `string` or both as `number` (previous section)

Therefore both arguments must be *at the same time* `string` and `number`, i.e. `string & number`. Which is unfortunately [`never`](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/narrowing.html#the-never-type) as described by @SilvioMayolo.

Note that we could still have a "valid" call to `example2` function:

```
// Using never type...
declare const arg: string & number; // Inferred as never
example2(arg, arg); // Okay!.. but should never be reached
```

At least, the return type (if they had one) follows the intuition:

```
declare const r2b: ReturnType<F1b | F2b> // string | number
parseInt(r2b) // Error! Argument of type 'string | number' is not assignable to parameter of type 'string'. Type 'number' is not assignable to type 'string'.
r2b.toFixed() // Error! Property 'toFixed' does not exist on type 'string | number'. Property 'toFixed' does not exist on type 'string'.
```

### What about the actual function that was assigned?

Unfortunately, even though we assign an actual function that can accept more diverse argument types (it could even have been unions with `boolean`, `null`, an arbitrary type, etc.; provided that it can be called one way or another as an F1, or alternatively as an F2), we lose the more tolerant behaviour by explicitly specifying the type of `example2`.

```
// Losing information of the actual function
const fn1d = (a: string | number | boolean, b: string | number | {a: number}) => {}
fn1d(true, {a: 1}) // Okay
const example1d: F1 & F2 = fn1d // Okay
example1d(true, {a: 1}) // Error! No overload matches this call. Overload 1 of 2, '(a: string, b: string): void', gave the following error. etc.

const example2d: F1 | F2 = fn1d // Okay
example2d(true, {a: 1}) // Error! Argument of type 'boolean' is not assignable to parameter of type 'never'.
```

In the case of `F1 | F2` union, the situation would have been different if we had assigned a *narrower* type instead, e.g. `(a: string, b: string) => {}`: here TypeScript would have followed the assignment, and inferred that we have a narrower type (as exactly described in https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/narrowing.html#assignments)

```
// Narrower type assignment
const example2c: F1 | F2 = (a: string, b: string) => {}
example2c("Hello", "World") // Okay
example2c(1, 2) // Error! Argument of type 'number' is not assignable to parameter of type 'string'.
example2c("Hello", 2) // Error! Argument of type 'number' is not assignable to parameter of type 'string'.
```

### What about `example3` to `example7`?

As pointed out by @SilvioMayolo's comment, these examples show how *assignment* is as expected.

Going further, we could describe their *usage* as well, but they would still be close to intuition:

```
declare const example8: {a: string} & {a: number}
const a = example8.a // never
parseInt(a) // Okay... but should never be reached
a.toFixed() // Property 'toFixed' does not exist on type 'never'.

declare const example9: {a: string} | {a: number}
const a9 = example9.a // string | number
parseInt(a9) // Error! Argument of type 'string | number' is not assignable to parameter of type 'string'. Type 'number' is not assignable to type 'string'.
a9.toFixed() // Error! Property 'toFixed' does not exist on type 'string | number'. Property 'toFixed' does not exist on type 'string'.
```

Only *arguments* of combined function types are really misleading.

[TypeScript Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBAYgjFAvFAFAQwFxQM7AE4CWAdgOYA0UARhroaQJRIB8UAbgPYEAmA3AFChIsAExJUmKEQCuAW0oQ8FatLkLGiFh278+AY3ZFcUCAA80MsABsIcLPCgAyEWPRZaxElAA+k2fMVUbvge3r6qeOosAN4Avnym5lY2KABEABIQlpbsKRQpAOrseJZcKfTxZhbWcChwFMLlAPSNxpVJNemZ2blQDVDNUACieHhFAIRh-lAE2JLswFBo2NgEJERolNZQwOxQYGh45hDAClDsAGbb4NDupAB0D+JEXGwEutCsCtho5XwDAPKfYrsNAvLgQGQGWhoYAEAwCa6wOCUFwSW7kQLoyI4YKkfiCaAwYQo5CuSYKJQYFT+bHUhQ6cG6SwHaD6QwLBJVGzUJEopxEyg6NlGPDIhDITntSipc7sHJ5SgHMp8fZ4bAQACSRGAKFFlDgjABAGs0CA+Hq4HcdjACCYIFwUIaWsNRngJgAFUaQPCgKAAcmttvtfqgXHYEFmRHmrRmCwMVyEfvRfr4eihCz1oglbWq0rqvXKqvVWp1madQxG4ygAEE8CRZBBtWdLgT-XS8CGZnMFksVmsNlsdnsDkcTnhmwnoEncSQ-XdzcjhFb2Da7Q7y-8TWa+IzmXhWemoHqAMxYABKxykeCIABVrgAeeB8kSUFgDfIAC0bUBvAGUoDIUhGLoH5yuqFAEAsQERtsX5QMyRjsEC2Sgsw5J4CqBzFtqurIse5YulWtb1jIjZxi2iJ+u2naRtGvarOsmzQEOqqjqcFyTv6ybziey6rvajr9C0m6mqmu4slAwoZsiAAs56Xted6QI+xKOLyb4tJ+35-gBQELCBYEQBBUHqrMwBwQhcbISCLwaDidAkJhaqajheoyRuW4LpQMl8UG65CRWroel6Ci+gGK5+SGYYwVGHImLGZxEJx04OSmqZSa0iTWMIdgID4RKokEDmhO2lL2SEPjttisR-C0krZakGRZPKUAFEUJRlAFhFujWdYNk2HGtui0y0T2ywMQOzG7KxpFjhOrZEBAQK1ZlXLCLU9QEZWPXEf15Gce2I3dos439kx2zTSOs3sRRQiLctAz1RA62dM1PR9AM3UTLtpEDbdNwzkdsUnX2jGDpdhzXeOg2IvdCipgMACqKykJIS2nASDzzuJ+6SYeBwkEVIROO2-BPetBMUAT9A8AFIkgGMjyUFICzYKBUglGjQJUNA+5oCB9piRATISRleDEvJwBXreD5PqEAoaeVqOVX48NFi5pbEltQW9SRZHzZRw0q+ENHHfRZ3g8OkPHDdyXcT+lHUUDdGnWDU12zOc7msSvlroJn3bcF7DemFgZrlF4ajTGiFJa2KUVehc5QJ6wehSA-ph8GoaR8dpgJfGcfcQjLQADLsCjnjELKeAyDCcJJYNcH81LaCWHjRC6PuJxQOcUgd7C8IZecRBwLZ4hE8r6GhJQcrWGgRBlUbU8+FEEjtjE1VxMPo8oPgUhGVAq9YHAG9055GVPaPuVqQVyDby8xqiZfDp7wfR9QCf2tVgAcrsSEKChF4tdgACzMh+LsuhW6WDuFAQEACbIfwnMICgfoyTokXjOegWAtBcD9BQEgaBPiwWgLKZqAB3EIChXQwOOLoecaZ2SrSSMILg198pZh7iPB+wlPLkxfngfeFB36fy6oHXWe0DaJhnuwOeRBTbA3Nm7C6Vs2LQ3+m2dGHZ6EDG-gcUYZCMaIkUb9YADCjDk10Gw5wpI0QzgwQ5TeFQsrPV0I1LoLU2rFFKB5J+OYXEbQLKInWP19Yw0TE7LsCjXaTWUTNG2aiPapXnBYtxb1NpBKIn1ExkipwRKjoomJLErrxJyVxT22iWgXz8aeZeStPDIFfhknqSloAACFZ4QHns7MaoNCm7AWqrccPh0RmLis4uStThrIDgKMph1gACsWBDrDMBsgFIsocjF3buYvxAA2LA790QxDUlEHk68xDv3WXKFIxyA46xaf6KIiwJ4kFpjEeRLtennSHHHJ5tiHJvJOYEdCbyk4rRTiHdOfpKCmxkDMCu0xY6UT+S80FVAWZHggAARykAQfcLxiDJSeWcwZoL5xVOcQAdgOf8jwxynCnKWYM45yBLkbJ6DyeZcQdzCz3AeRhT0AAcNKXn0sPmvZlsy0BiCFXcaVAw4YYXViWdAPiQBY3RazdmnNFU80xfzL8XA+BoF9gJcsEK04ZwiuHbOMVox5xjslRVXseUi1xhSrkABOEVdTjkrwleEOIGU0CeplX4z1cqApL3bE5bCOoQ1fx2lk0J6j46TzyWbaJ3yIaqNKWm2cMCHlUUGR8npE1s2JI8F7ENpr-J3KrBan0ULM64NtVHB1cYkWJmjSWmBjbQ7WqztFdt8VHWF3KUAA)

Comment: Those pictures really clarify things. `The situation would have been different if you had assigned a narrower type instead` Ohhhhh! OK, that helped a lot. I think I was focused on `F1 <operator> F2` more than I should've. The right hand side of the `=` seems to be responsible for the majority of my confusion.

Comment: The `But I did assign...` title and paragraph that follows is throwing me off. The rest of it was extremely helpful, but would it be possible to rewrite those parts using different words? I know what a method override is (at least in other languages), but the way you're using it, I'm not connecting the dots.

Comment: I see how it could be confusing. I will try to reword it.

Comment: Hello.have you edited this yet?

Comment: Yes, let me know if you still find that part confusing.

Answer (score 0):

As types are nothing bet sets, It all follows the Set theory.

First, let's understand a crucial behavior of `&` in type system.

`{ a: 'number' } & { b: 'string' } => {  a: 'number', b: 'string' }`

Both of the constituents types got added as they were independent types.

Keeping this in mind, let's try to prove this behavior and what should be the equivalent result of `F1 & F2` and `F1 | F2`

```
type F1 = (a: string, b:string) => void;
type F2 = (a: number, b:number) => void;



Using SET Theory

Eq 1.  (A | B) = A + B - (A & B) 
Eq 2.  (A & B) = A + B - (A | B) 

Also, our F1 and F2 are independent type sets, hence

Eq 3. F1 & F2 => F1 + F2


Case 1: F1 & F2

> F1 + F2     ...(By using eq 3)
> (string, string) => void + (number, number) => void 
> Basically means we can only call F1 and F2 with their own types (not their union one)

 

Case 2: F1 | F2


> F1 + F2 - (F1 & F2)    ....(By Using Eqn 1)
> F1 + F2 - (F1 + F2)    ....(By using Eqn 3)
> never (as everything cancels out)
```

Comment: I apologize for being dense, but I think set theory is *more* abstract (and perhaps complex) than the concept in question. Therefore, explaining it in these terms isn't clarifying my understanding.